# Strange Symbols in browser

Tags: browser

Can someone say me what is this and how to prevent it?

[image]

Not only image now, but the symbols aswell

̇͋ͭ̂ͩ̄̌ͯ͊̆ͫ̂̅̊͒̽ͦ̒̆̐̾͆̓̔̓̂͋͆ͭ̐̌͛ͫ̃̾͑̽ͧͭ̎ͥ̓̂͆͊̈́͐́̓ͪͧ͋͋̽̍̆̊̋̐̈́̈͋ͬͯ̎̉̓͗̈̒ͪͭ̐͆̽̄͛̓ͣͦ̏̌ͪ̈̔̇̀͆̉͋̀́ͦ̃̓ͬ̉̒ͮͫͫ́̆̒͐̄̾̄͋̓̇ͤͯͨ͋ͧ̀̽ͮ͊̓ͮ̎͐̅̏̇͂̔̐̍͛̃̄͐ͯ̌̋̐ͪͭͣ̀ͫ̇ͮ͑̂ͫ̒͋̌̇̓̾͛̐͗ͬ͗ͤ̄̆̈́̇̔̂̌̍̉͂̄̒̾ͫ̀̉̐̑́̍̋͛͂̊ͭ̇̋͗̐̄ͦ̎ͪ̿͒͗̑ͧ̑̈̏̓̒͛ͫ͒̄ͩ̉̑̓̈͌͐ͨ̏͌͛ͥ̂̓̈́̉́ͩ͛̆͊̍̂́̌͂ͥͦͪ̆̆̃͊ͦ̓̉̌͊̑̊͌̋̽͂̉̒̋͑̈́ͬ̊ͪ̉ͯ͂͒̆̆ͭ̌͌̈́ͥͬ̔͑́̑̒̿ͭ̐ͬͧͥͣ͂̎̎̉ͦͤͬͦ͛̈́̆̅͋̄̏͗̽ͧ̅̓ͩͨ́̅ͯͦ̒̎ͪ͋͗̅͛̏͗̿̄̃̃̿̾ͤ̾̽̒̋̄̉̓͛̾̄ͤ̐̅̓͌ͫͪ̉̒̐̔̆͒ͧ͊̽͑̓̑̔ͦ͋̂̔̂̆̌̽ͤͤͩ̈́̆̋̉ͥ͒̏ͪͥ͒̿ͣ̇̉͋͊̂͑̌͂̒ͧͩ͊ͤͨͥ̄̓ͩ̿̾ͬ͆ͣ͆̿̂ͪͬ̑̆͛̊́ͫ̾͛̌ͩͤ̃͒̿͋̽̃̍̋̐̑ͤͩ̒̏̇͌̀ͭ̓̅͋́̃ͮͪ͛ͮ̔̽̐̄͐̐̄͗ͧͯ͑ͧ̉ͮͦ̂̏̐̈̃͗͗ͧ̀ͯ̄̉̋ͦͯͧ̃͐ͦ̉̊ͦͮͯ͑̈́̋̒̌̍͗̾͛́̓͒͐́͆ͣͦ̀̽̆͂ͧ̒̌͌̈́̾͒̏̓̽͋̒̓̎͆́ͫ̇̈́ͯ̋ͫ͑̂̃ͧͨ̇̈́̑ͥͧ̈ͧ̔ͤ̽̀̑͋̉͗̅ͮ̈́ͯͫ͆̑̓ͤ̓̆̌̌͂͐͂̄͐͗ͨ͋͊̂̈́̎́͆͊͆̑̓ͨ̔͒̓ͮ͂̎͑̑ͪͦ̀̈̎ͨ̊̃̓̏ͦͥ̎̀̄͊͂̇́̍ͣͯͫ̅ͫͪͯ̈́ͣ̍̅̀͌͛ͪͧ̄ͫͫ̒ͦ̈ͧ̑͂ͭ͊̀̋ͫ͐̈̆̊͒ͯ̄̓̄͐̄͌ͯ̿̾ͣͣ̆͂ͤ̊̑͗̍ͥ̀ͫ͛́ͤ̓̂̔̉ͧ̄ͥ͆̀̓͆͛͗̌̋̀̅̋̊̈́̾ͥ͂ͫ̍̎̐͆ͦ̇͋̇̔̂̃̈́̓̉ͤ̀ͣ͐̑ͪ͑ͪ͗̄̆̾ͣ̋̒̋ͩ̈̈̎̉̌͆̒͌ͭ̓͌͂̍͌͆ͭ̂̇ͩ͗ͩ̅ͮ̋͋̃̔̒̽̏̔̓̿ͤ́̌ͨ̃ͦͪ͗̓̈̌̏̓ͥ͛͑̇̽̀̍̀ͥͩͦ̾̏͛ͫ͐͂̂́̀ͨ́͐ͣ̈̉̓͑̓̒ͩͪ̀ͯ̓̿ͫ̿ͫ̋ͥ̄̑ͦ̿́͛ͥ̔ͦ̒̿̀ͨͤͨͥ̐̄̍̀̋ͤ͐̇͆̂̑̀̑̀͆̉̇̃̉̓ͧ͐ͦ̔̆̓͂͊̀̂ͣ͆̃̈̆ͮͬ͛ͪͬ̉̌̂ͩ̋͗ͪ̅̌͗̊̌͐̈́̎ͯ͋͛̃̽͋̿̽͛͒ͧ̓ͭ̐̏̂̂̇̈́͗ͯͩ͆̓̒ͭ̆̃̍̾ͮ̾̋̌͐̊ͤͮ̀ͤ̒͆̐̈́̀͗̓̆ͭ̌̾̉͛ͣ̽ͤ́͛̿̂̂̉ͣͯ̀̏ͯ͊ͮ̄ͤͮͩ̇̋̈ͦ͛ͦ́ͧͤͪ͛ͯ̋̃̔̈͐̄̒̌̅̑͊ͭͯ̽́ͩ̊ͣ͒͌ͭ̅͆̋̓̉͂ͦ̿ͭ̓ͩͮ͒ͥ͒ͬ͋ͨͨͪ̿ͩ͗̐̈́̉̾̔̾̊̔̏̾ͤ̑̂̄̈̔̓́̏̅͗̓̇ͭ̊ͣ̄̂̀̌̄ͤͥ̀͑̐́̑̆̾͂̏̋̇͆͗́ͮ͆ͭͤͬͫͫͬ̇̋̾̾̇̐ͫͯͦ̏ͨ̃ͦ̆͗̑̊ͩͣ͐̉̊̊̊̅͒̈́̐̓͂ͫ̿́̀ͬͤ͐ͮͥ̈̅̍̔ͬͮͤ̌ͤ̓̅͗͋̎̃ͦ̈̿͌́ͬ̄ͧ̋͂ͯ̊̄ͥ̓̎͌ͪ̏͒̅͌̍ͮ̈̽̃̓ͨͣ̃̌̏̓ͨͤͯͦ̋̉ͯ͆̈́̓̔̔͆̆͂̏ͪ̎ͨͫ̈́̽͒ͩͯ̇͊ͨ̈́̉̾͆̐̔͒̿ͦ̀̑͐̍͌̈ͮ̍ͪ̑ͧ́͊̑̋ͮ͒͑ͪ̋ͫ̏̓͒ͥ̾̓ͪ̍ͮͥ̀ͭ̆ͩ͐̈́͋̽͆́̐ͫ̐͗́̋͂̓ͩ̅ͯ̾̈́ͬ̅͗̄̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚Tͥ̒̈̉̏̇̅ͯͪͧ͛̂̍̏́ͯ̀̆̆̑̓͂͂̋͛̉̽̓̅ͧͫͤͫ͊̈ͣ̋̋̏̌͌ͧ̃̽͌̃ͦͤ͛̎̓͆̍ͩͨ͌̐̂͗́ͭͤ̄̋ͯ̾ͮͭ̉͗ͥͩ̾̔ͮͥ̌͒ͥͦ̐͊̎ͬͥ́͆͊̿͌ͫͣ͛͗̂̆̽͛̇͆͌̎̆̆̽ͨ̔ͩ͛̉̓́̋̋̉́̎ͩ̔ͬ͒́͋ͥ̉ͥ̋́ͨͫ̔ͯ̾ͧͮͥ̀̈̆͊͒͆͆̌̃̋̾̆ͨͫ̓ͤ͊̉ͯ́ͩ̒ͮ͗͑ͯ̂̉̌̑̑̈́̓ͭ̔̒̋̿̽͋̐̀ͮ̊͒̿̎ͭͭ͆̊ͧ̏̾̿̄̽ͧ̽ͯ͐͆ͣ͂̈́͋̎̆̓̓̓͗̾ͨ̐̐ͣ̋̐ͪͫ̈́̐̓̈́ͫ̍̒̏̓ͣ̑̈ͧ̆̑ͮ͌̉̓ͫ͐ͮͬ̈́̒ͯ̾ͭ̔̇͑͆̓̓̂̊̉̈̏ͨ͌͒̽͌̊̽̂̐̓̊ͪ̓̿̌ͥͭ̌͊̔͗̋̊͂ͣͩͮ̉͂̌ͩ̒ͭ̀̊͋͊͒͐̊̐́ͤ͂̄ͣ̑́̏ͣ̿̑̽̾́ͧͩ͛̾͋̌̃͐͛̊̑͒̂͐ͪͦ̐͒ͮ̾̽̄̿͑͌ͦͨ̎ͯͨ̓̈ͧ̎ͫ̅ͮͦ̊̆ͥͨ̉ͧͭ͊͐͆ͥͣ͂́̑ͭ̂̓ͮ̾ͯ̓͛͛̒͒͊͆̅ͯ̊̅ͥ̑ͩ̓̒̍̂̍ͯ̊͛̅̑̌̏͛͂̏̃͌̆͗̌ͨ̓̋͑̎̅ͨ̆ͪ̈͆̆̈́̾̃̇̐̀ͧͤ̈̀̒̆ͩͤ̑͛͆ͣ̅̓̉ͯͨͨ̓̇̂ͣ͑̑́̽̓̽ͪ́͊̓́̂ͫ̓̓̅ͫ͊̽ͯ̀̎ͤ̽͛̆̊ͯ̈̏̽̉̈́̓̊̈̅ͫͩͤ̋̈́͊̋ͮͧͯ͗ͣͩͤ̈̇̐̔ͦ͒̓ͭ͆ͥͩ̎̂̐͂͛͐̌ͤͨͮ̈́̂̾̄͋͆̑̏ͬͦ̆̐͋̔̎̑͗̔͋̍ͮ̆̋̈́̂̅̔̌̏̌͐̎̾̽͒͒̏ͪͧ̈͂ͨ̀͒̑̋̓̏ͣͫͨͩ̇̓͂͋͑ͦ̈̇̈́ͬ̽̏̑͆͑ͧͮ̎̽̋ͣ̍͋ͦͬ̒͐̇ͦͤͧͯ̀̊̾͊̎͋̐ͨ̒͗̒̓̾̃̃̽̑ͬ͛̆̔ͣ̿͆̎ͦ̔̔̅ͩ̋ͥͭ̐ͧ̀̒͋͊ͨ̎͒ͤ́͌ͨ̽̌ͭͬͮͥͫͤͦ̑̀̋̄ͮ͌̀ͬͪ̑̈ͣ̉̍̄̒ͤ̂̒ͮͣ̋̉ͤͭͪ̅͆̈́̽ͮ̌ͫ̎͂ͤͨ͐͌͑͑̄ͯ͋͒̊͆̏̽͗̎ͭ̎ͪ̅ͯ̎̅̎̊͌ͯ̏ͨ̑ͦ̇̋ͬ͒ͯ̀ͭ̃̄̉ͨ́̍̆̓̔͑ͯ̋̎̏̂̎͆͐͋̆̊ͤ̍̄͑̓̑̍ͮ̏̌̊̈́̆̽̀̊̂̒́́̆̅ͪ̈́̎͐͛̒̐ͬ̽͑̾ͫ̎͆͆̔ͩ͛̊̔ͬͥ̐̄̀̓̊̇͗̃ͬͬ̿͌ͯͪ̒ͦ̍͌̓ͯ͂͛̓̉ͣͦͥ͊̅̃͌͋ͯ̏͋̈̈͌͊̿ͮ̒̃͐̑͊̾̓ͦ̄̒̍͒̉ͭ̿̌̄̇͊̈́͊̆̆̅̒̏͆̓̆̉͊̋̆̈͐͗ͩ̅ͫ̈́̍ͤ́ͭ͒͌ͮ̉͊̄͑̓͌̐͛̏ͦͦ̆̍̔̾͒ͤ̐͋̒̔ͥ̎͂̈͐̎̿̅̽̉ͯ͋̌́̈́͌̀̍͊̅̈́ͨ̏̾̂̓ͫ̒͊ͯͥ̈́ͦ̆̇̌ͧ̌̒ͪ̅̑̇̎̑̃͐̋̽ͣ̇̍̆̉ͦ̎͌̈̀̍̆ͨ̔̓̐͐̿ͩ̾̽̏ͩͣ͂͑̓ͮ͋̀ͩ̏ͧ͐̃ͮ̄ͮ͋͒̾ͩ͋͗͛̍̒ͣͩ̽ͩ̒ͬ̓ͫͬ̊̒̉ͧ̀̿̌̎̋ͤ̇ͯ̏̐̔͆ͤ̓̽̔ͧͫ͆͛̒̾̅̉ͭ̽̾ͩ̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚h̅͌̐̾̐̏͛̍ͣ̓̄̑̆́͌ͪ̿̋ͯ͊͊̈̐͆ͥ̂̾ͤ͗̇̋̍̂̔ͫ̂̑̊̂ͧ̅ͦ͒͛ͥ̇̍̉̐͗̃ͧͧ͌ͧ̊ͧͨ̓̇ͪ̉ͬ̃ͬͯ͌͌͊͛ͦ̔̀͒ͯ͊̿̒ͦͪ̈͆͐̆͂͛̆̓ͬ͆ͩͭ̾̌̋̉̋̔̀͌ͨ͆̿̓̔̽ͣ̅́ͤͤ̈ͯ̓̾ͧ̓̈́̿ͥͨ̔͌́̏̈́̽̐̄̾͌ͤ͊ͬͬ̿͋͗ͬͤͬ͗̅͛ͧ̀͒ͣͣ͐̈͋̈̒ͨ̈ͤͨ̓͌͛ͮ̅̎ͮͧ̈̔ͯ̋̃̇̀̆̉̾̋̄̂͆ͥ̃͆̌ͧ̐̔̊̆͌ͬͨ̄ͣ̃ͥ̎̋̓̽̍̿ͬ̇͐͌̅̽̾ͮ̓̂ͫ͊̆̔ͤ̐ͯͤ̐͐̍ͪ̈́̌̿ͪ́͐̃ͫ̈ͨ͑̔̑ͤ͌͑̓̆̍͋͒ͬͬ̑͆ͫ̓̓̅ͣ̔͋ͩ̌̋̌͆̓͆̊̐̊́̇̂̊ͦ̇̋ͣ͒͊ͫ̃ͩ̌̇ͦͦ̽̐ͦͩ̅̋͒̊͐͒͆̐͌ͩ̇̒̍́̓ͤ̾̍̋ͫ͂̏ͥ̿ͧ͐͂́̈̅͑ͣ̽ͬ̃̾̔̈́͑̈͐̂̏͒͐̐ͨͨ͊̈̎̆̿ͥ̾̿͗̅͂̆͂̉̓ͤ̓̄̂̾̊̋̌͛͆̋͑̌̔̔ͯ̔̿̄̆͐ͯ̓̉̐̐͑ͧ͒̈ͤ̓ͫͮ̇̋͐ͪ̎̉͂͆ͭ̃̊ͨͬ̌͒ͮͯͧͯͧ͌̂͗̾͊ͦ́̋̅͂͂̾̆ͫ̊̅̀̑̇̿̎̃̔̌ͪ̂ͫ̍͊ͥͧ͗̐̿̽͛̆̎͌̓̚̚̚̚̚̚̚e̍̑ͦͬͫ̊ͦ̃ͤ̓͑̽͊̅̐̇̊̐ͭͩͩ̂ͮ̾ͥ̇͑͌ͣ̑͊̏̋ͬͧͪ̊̈́ͧ̅ͥ͗̎ͣ̆ͦ̔̃̈́̓͒͆̎͂̃̈̄͒̓ͪͫ́͑̇̍͌ͪͯ͒̋͑̀̋ͯ͑́ͯ̓ͮ̍̂͋̌͂͂̉̍͗͑ͯ͊̔ͯ̓͒̓̐͗͊͌̽̎̄̉̇͐̂͑ͫ̍ͨ͆̎̏̏̃̑̄ͯ̈ͪ̒ͪ̾̒̓ͨ̓͌̃ͦͮͬ͋ͥ̾̓̀͋̉ͣ̉̆̉̋̐̔ͯͪ̃ͬͦ̐̔ͥ̓̈̒̿̽̓ͣ͗̆͒͊̑̃ͯ̇̌̋͌̈͛͊̓ͣ̎̈́ͧ̅̒̋ͪ͊̾̾̈̒ͨ̄̍ͬͫ̌̉͗ͯ̆̇ͬ̃̽̅̑͛͋ͬ͑͊́̎ͮ̿̔͌̋ͧ̉̐͆ͩ͌̈́͊̏ͧͭͬ͊́̒̍̇ͪ̏ͭ̓̒̏̏̈́͑͌̐ͮͤ̐ͨ̎͐͒̒̆ͩ͒͋ͤͩ̋̀ͧ͗̀̎ͩͨ͂̓̉̀̂ͭ͊̈ͤ̈́ͮ̂̌̋̊̊̓͊̀ͨ͛̐͐̈́ͪ̓̄͒͂ͤ͌̔̇̽̆ͩ̍́ͫͮ͆͒̽͆̌͐̄ͣ̈̅̆ͨ͊͐ͧͮ͋̊̅̊̿̑̽̎͗͌ͭ̐̿͆͑̓̓̊̎̾ͣͣ̓̑̓̇ͣͧ͛̋̆͛̀̑͆̉̅ͦ̆̓ͣ̐̍̉ͮ̎͑͛̈̑̿̍ͣ͂ͤͤ̃̂ͭ̈́̄ͩͭ̈̿̉̐̍̓͌̽̐ͣͨ͐̀̀ͦ̐̆ͧͫ͐ͮͮ̊ͤ̏ͥ̋̆̎̆̊͌̿͌͌̔̀ͫ͐̃̈́ͫ̈́ͭͫ͐̄̀ͭ͌͋̉ͦͥͫͤ̋̋ͩͦ͋̆̈͌ͣ̅̐ͥ͒ͬͯͥ̇̎͌͊͆̓ͤͩ̐͋̀ͣͮ̌͑ͬ̂̅ͧͨͪ̐ͫͧͦ̏̏̒͗͌̐̒̀͗̆ͬ͗̆̋́ͩ̽ͦͫ̎̊́ͯ̔̾̑̾͐́̔̈́̐̾̒ͭ͗̈́̄̐̓̋͂̊̓̐̃̉͒́ͮ̑͗͂̏ͧ̊͊̒̀̐ͦ̾ͧ̾̋ͮ̔́̆̀̈́̽̑͒͌ͥ̓̐͂̋ͩͪ̐͊̎͋̿̉̅ͤ̉̐̅̓̃͒͑̿̀̍̄̿̓͛͗͐̒ͯ̊́ͥͪͧ̃̏ͩ̑̄͑̏̌̌͐ͪ̿͌̋̊̈͊ͮ̊̔̔̿ͫ̊ͩ̿̅̊͌͗̅̌ͥͯ͗̿ͭ̿ͦ̉̆̆̐ͧͭ͛ͯ̃̍̎ͩͭ̀̃ͨͫͥͣ̓͆̀̓ͥͥ̿̾̒ͭͨ̄̐̔͒̃͊͊ͮ͊ͪ̅ͯ̔́̋̔ͥ͒ͧ̆͐͑̊ͯ̾̈̽ͥ̃̇̅͌̃̈́͆̀͛͐̓ͭ͑̄ͤ̏ͮ͆̏́̋̓ͮ͛ͯͤͮ̅̾̉̒̀̆̃ͫ̐ͤͫͨ͗̊͆̈̈́̌̄̈́̅̌̆̋̆̇ͮ͗̓̈́̐̎̇ͩͧͥ̈́ͭ͐̒͌ͣͥͩ̑͗ͫ̓̾͐ͣ͂̅̆̌̎ͪ̂̂̂̓ͫͦ̇̽ͭ̐̍̐ͭ̑̓̍̓̎ͦͭ̐ͫ̊ͯ̂ͧͩͦ̊ͪ̂̄ͫ̓̎ͧ̔̈ͧ͂͆̃͆ͦ̀ͩ͐̔̂͋ͤ̂ͫ͑̌̅͊ͣ͋̃ͨͮ͋̿ͦ̌̽ͭͭ̇ͦ̎͌͑̋̿̑͊́̏͑̒͐͆ͤ́̀̇̂͛̍̄͒̈͂ͣ̊ͥͦ̍̂ͩ̂͌͒̊̊̌ͮ͊̈́̒̇ͦ̎͛̋ͯ̓́̒̀͐̌̈ͤ̅ͤ̐ͧ̉̋̓͐̓̈ͥͥ́ͮͤ͐͌̉̆͆ͥͬ̊ͮ̓̽̌̅̿̄̿̏ͨ̂̄ͥ̄͐ͧ̈́͊ͬͤ̔̈́̓̄ͭͨͥ̈́̀̾̎ͤ̊̈ͤ͛̆̇̈́͛̏̍ͯͯ̓̽́ͤ̾͂͒̓ͦ̅̔ͤ͌ͦ̆ͤ͛̃́̑͒̉̾̾̈́̊͆ͬͧͤ͊̈́͌̃͌̈́̐͌ͦ͋̋͋͛̋ͤ̐̃͌ͫͭ̅͑̇̅͂͋ͤ͊̇̀̈͗̽͌̀ͧ͆͋̍̈̾̃̅̂̆̃ͯ̍̄ͦͥ̔ͩ͊ͮͩ͑̍̈͛̊ͬͦ̀ͮͧͧ̎͒͌̀ͭ̔̾ͯͪ̊̓̓ͭ̑ͬͩͤͤͥ͊̎̀̐͒̋̑̒ͭ̐̓̉̾ͧ͛̂ͤͨ͂͑̑͆ͥͥ̆ͯ́̄͌ͭͩ̂̀͗͛̊ͪ͌̉̎͒ͮ̈̌̂̾ͨͭ̐̇ͦ͂̌̎̏ͣ̔ͪ͌̀ͭͬ̅͐̋͆̊̈́͗̋̓̄͊̂ͫ̈́ͧ̈́̑͑͆̓͒̄̒ͪ͒̄̉̎ͯͥͧ̐̐̆̆ͦ͋̈͋̅̋̏ͤ̀̎̃͆ͧͧ̀̐̓̊ͮ͐̄͊͂̓̂͊͒̽̃͒̑̇̍̌̉͛ͯ̍̋ͬͥͯ̔͂̓͋̃ͯ̃̈̈́̽ͣ̇ͦ̈̎̃ͬ̑ͧ͊͑͆̓̈͑́ͣ̓͒̉̍ͩ̓ͦ̿ͬ̈́ͬ̂͛͌ͬͤ̉̌̂͋̈͌͂̏̾ͧ̔̀̇ͮ̍͐̐ͭͭ̈́̇́̍͌ͯ̔̿̔͐ͩ̐͂ͯ̌̊ͫ͗̇̀̋̈́́̇͐͋̃̐̈ͩ͒̏ͨ̿̌ͯ̔̽͐̽̒̈̈́ͩ̑̓̓̒̅̋̀ͥͣ͋̑͋͗͆͌͊̄͑̍̀̈́͛͗͊ͥ͌ͦ͐͛̓̓̂̈ͭ̃ͩͨ͛ͧ͑ͬ͒ͮ̅̄̓̊͐ͯ̄̈́̆͐ͤͫͯ͂̎̿̏̌͊̏ͬͯͬͧ̿̋̈ͪͥͤ̓ͬͨ̆͂ͦ͆͆ͭ̽ͨͩͭͮͬ͋ͣ̂ͣ̔͂̓ͬ͆͂ͥͥͤͨ͌̏͒̈̔̏ͣ̉ͩ̉ͥ̾̍̏ͪ̒̓̿͛ͤ͗͒̄͒̇̅͆ͪ̎͆̃͒ͤͪ͌̽̃́ͪ̈͂̽̋̄̑̈́ͤ̈̄̈́̓̾ͬ̄̎ͣ̌̃ͮ͑ͧ͋̓̾ͩ̈̈͌͂̐ͧ̓̀͛̿͑̿̾͑̋ͥ̓͌̋̎͑̃̅ͬ̄̿̅ͮ̇̋͛ͤ̓̅̓̎̅̂͌̿̏ͣͦ̃ͣͨͥͫ̉ͧͭ̐ͨ̉̅̃̔̃̋ͭ̈ͧͪ̇͊̊ͨͩ̓͑̽͛ͨ̓͋̈̅̇ͦ͂̈́́͐ͥ͋ͦ͗ͯ͒̾̅̓̏̍ͥ̀̊̔̈́ͩͯ̋͂̋̓̓̽̃͑̊̆̽̎̿ͦͦͩ͐̾͊ͤ͐̎͋̈̌ͣ̃ͬ̓ͨ͑͆̎̆ͭ̓́̒̅̐̇̆̉̈́ͤͥ͂̾̂̽̊͛̐̀̓̄ͪ̓̔̿͗̏́̾̓̐ͪͩ̄ͮ̂̈́̂͐ͩ̄̍̇̊͒̋̄ͧͮͦ̓̅́͐͌̎̾͂́͋́̇̑̊̉ͭ͂̔̾ͣ̎̊ͥ̃͊ͭ̊ͬͤͮ̓ͬ̓̅̔ͭͩ͑͋͌͐ͭͣ̎͆ͦ͌̊̌̾ͫ̍͂ͫ̂̄ͮ͐̏͊ͦ͑ͪ͑̅͆͊̇̽̀̀̂͋ͫ́̀̂ͭ͐̉́͋̽́ͣͣ̏ͤͦ̿̀ͭͫ͗̊̿́̉͆̾̎͊͑̄̌ͬ̏͋̓̆̊͑̌͋ͣ̏̈͆͐̿ͫͬ̋̅̎̋͒ͣ̈́ͥ̋́ͩ́͐ͨ̓͛͆̽ͩ̃ͤ̋͐̑͌̒ͩ̐͊͐͆͌̌͐ͨ̿̂͒̇̒̿̓ͥ̄ͥ͆̔̈̉͆ͣ̓́ͨͨ͐͑̀̇ͨ̋̀̆̆ͧͨ̍̈̍̃̓ͮ̍͊̈͐̅͂͂ͦ͗͆̉ͥͪ̇ͪͫͪ̓̇̾̌͛ͩ̍̒̈́̑̒̀̀̍̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚ ͥ͛ͬͫ̇̿ͣͩ̓̌͋ͭ̉̿͒̋ͨ̿̎ͧ́́̓̎̀̓̑̃̓ͫͭ̅̾ͦͧͬ̓ͪ̽ͣ̋ͧͤ̂͋͋̍́̔ͦͣͭͣ̃̿̽̏̎̌̍̐̒͂͑ͩ͛̈́ͥͬ̋ͮ̐ͯͮͤ͗̉ͬ͐̏̊̓ͤ͗ͮ̽̇̽ͣͩ̅̏̌́̐̐̑̔̑̍̉̆ͦͮ̌ͩ̍ͧ̾̋̌ͩ̈́͂̐ͪ̂́̈́̆̊̏ͥ̉̒ͮ͌̏̿̌̈͒͛͗̋͗́̃̈́̍̃ͣ̆̇ͤͨ͆̂̅ͦͣ̐̂͐ͧ̽͑̓͛ͧ̔̐͋̽̂͆̂̈ͣ͆̇̈̌̋ͪ̍̅̃̽͛͆̑̇̾̾ͨ̐ͪ̈́ͥ͛̏͗̇ͣ͂̔̑͛̊ͨ͊͑̆͒̇ͧ͗ͬ̐ͣ̑͛͌ͨ̈͗̀̌̀̏̉͒̿̒ͫ͋ͥͥͣ̇ͤ͂̿ͩ̀ͩ̊ͭ̋͒̒ͬ̿̈͋ͣͧͤ̾̈̾ͬ̒̓̋̋ͨ̎̏͌ͧ̃ͥ̐͆͗̑̅́̒͐̑̍͌͌͂̅ͥ͂͑̅ͩͭͧ̊̀ͨͣ͒̾͆̔̋̈̑ͧ͑̑̊͗̃ͫ͆̇ͪ̔͆̌̑ͦ͋́͛̔͋̆̈ͣͧ͑̆͑͊̓̔ͧ̉ͤ̐ͪͤ̂̆̉ͧ͋̓̈̅̆͐̊͌ͬ̇͊̆͛ͥ͋ͫ̿̂͐̎̆ͣ͆̾͒͊̾̐̒ͬͬ̐̈̿ͦ̊͗̎̌ͯͬ͋̊̑́̎ͥ̉̉ͯͥ̂̍͂͒ͩͫ̂͂̆̋ͣ̐́̀͊̀̑͑̊̎̓̓̂̾ͦ̔̊̅̌̒́̍̽͗̔͗̿̏̈́̂̉̋̿̿͆͑̄̋ͥ̑ͭͣ̂̆ͣͣ͌̍̽̒̄̓ͤͯͪ̐͆̌̿̇ͨ͋ͪͥͨ͋̒̔͂͒̔ͦͤ̐ͥ̐ͨ̓ͧ͌ͫ̾ͫ̽̿ͯ̂͗̔̎̑̑̒͊͛̍͛̾͑ͦ̆ͦͮ̿̉ͭ͊ͩͫͦ̅͌͒̓ͧ̓̓ͭ͌̃͋̂͑͑̈́ͨͣ̾̇̾͌́̾̅ͩ̒͊̽̐͆̑͐ͫͬ͑͌ͣͯ̑͛̑͐ͥͫ͑̐̓͆͆͊̉ͭ͌̂͌̓͆ͯͮ̀̍ͯ̅̓̇̃̎̄͐͑́͐ͫ̓ͬ̂ͮ͒̏̓͗̈́̎͌ͯͥͦ͊ͯ̂ͨ͒̍̈͗̋͋̉͑ͨ̈́̍͑̊ͦͫ͒ͣ̍̍ͦ̋͒͂́ͥ̀ͣ̇͐ͦͤ͑ͭ̽ͪ̍ͬ͊̈́͒̎̓̃̐̃̋͊̐͌ͦ̐̎̒̀͛̌ͦ̾̔͋̐ͧ͆́ͩ̈ͪͥ̌͐̍͐ͯͦ͛̿̽̓̆̏͂ͦ̿ͦͩͦ̽̈ͪ̂ͬ̒̀ͦ̏̐͌͛͑̒́ͧͨͬ̋̌͐ͤͪ̾̏̑̓̈́̆ͮ́ͩ͒̈̒͌̋̂̄͗̔̽̆ͪͣ̽̓̐ͨͭͣ̿͂̏͒ͪ̈́ͧͤ͆͋̀͆̎̀͌͑ͧ̈́̔ͧ̉ͨ̇͗ͯ̆͊ͯ͆ͬ͗ͮͩ̾̍̆̔̾̔̃̄ͬ̓͌̎̒̽ͨ͛̓ͩͤ̉͛̍̄̓̃ͨͭ͑̏̿̂̎ͥ̓̒̄͛̆̎̄͋ͬͧ̂͒ͩ͋̍̈͋͑̊̀͋̊ͦ͗̔͒̽̽̑̏̍ͪ̍̓̐ͫ͌̿̐̄ͦ̈ͯ̅̌͑̄̓͐̑̓̉̒ͬͫ̃͒̇ͥͫͨ͛̔͑ͪͤͪ̉̇̊̃ͥͨ͐̌̔ͪ͂̅͛̅͗͂ͭ̒̾ͥ̽ͥͪͣ̌̍̉ͦ̍̅̄ͤ͑ͤͯͪͥ̈̒͗ͮ̍̒̽̎̊ͫ͆̂̾̎ͨ̿̑ͪ̊͗̑ͩ͌̈̏̔͗͆ͭ̆͂͊̍̽̏͗̃ͭ͌ͭ͑̉ͭ͛ͯ̋ͧ̆̍̊̿͒̌̂̓̍̒̄ͫ̊͒͐ͤ̐ͧ͐̓̽ͧͯ̍ͬ̇͋ͣ̆̀͛̾̓̓ͭ̇̊͒̈́ͭ̄ͭ̅̇ͥ͒́ͮ̿́͂̓̌̓̀̓̒͛ͫ͌ͦ̈̌͗͛ͯͪ͋̿̆ͪ̐̾ͬ̌ͪ͆̃̐̅̇̊̈́̊̌̓͊̉̍̅ͣ̍͒̅̐̑̔ͣ̏͛̅̌̇̈͋ͦͬ̈̊͌̅ͮ̈͐̉̓ͧ̾̀͆ͫ̒̅̉͐ͩ̾͋̔̑͆̋ͮͪͤ͋ͯͬ̍͑ͣ̓ͦͨͫ̄̈ͯͫ̂ͯ̎͋̎̾̋͌ͯ̈́ͩ̆ͯͮ͊̈̇̎͆́̉͗̈ͭͫ̑̒ͯͬ̽̏ͣ̔̂̈́̍̌̐̅̓ͨͯ̊͂̿͛͒ͣ͗ͨ̒ͮ͋ͥͣ́̎ͣ͑̎̒͗̅͑̋ͣͫ͐͗͂͐͒̔ͩ̿̈́ͬ̿̐̌̔͑ͬͪ̐̒̀̔̄̊̃̐ͮͪ̌̑ͦͧ̉̄ͬͧ͑ͦ͛̆̅̈̃̉́̉͂͗̎̂̓͆̎͊͊̂̇̿̿̿̓͋͊̓ͯ̀ͮ͌̀ͪͩ̽ͥ̿͐̀̎ͣ̄͒͒͑̍͆̓ͩ̃͋ͦ̑͆͐̈̌ͯ̉̃͌͊ͭ̈̾̔̅ͨ̍ͪ̆ͣ͛ͪ̈́̾̆̂̓͒̄ͧ͂ͣ͛ͩ͒̽́̑ͬ̊̽̆̂͑͂̌̉͗̆ͨ̓̂ͥ͐̈́̓̏͒̎ͪ͌ͣ̌̌ͮ̽̏ͣ̊̌͆̉ͥͤ̏̽͊̀̒̾̏ͣ̌̿ͣͫͩ̐̿͊͗ͮͪ͋̀ͭ̇̾̋̉ͫ͊̐̇̆̏̓̇ͩ͛͒̾̐̐ͬ͗͗͆̃̑ͤ͗ͮͥ̓͗̓ͨ̌̒̏̍̾͒̔̔̇͋͛̄̊̐ͫ̔̊͊̐̉̓ͧ̆̍̔͐͛́͒ͪ̄ͨ̏̋ͥ̄̑̐ͤ̃̈́̐͗͌͗ͬ̍̂ͮ̉ͩͩ͒̍ͦͯͥ̃̊̎ͤ̈̒ͨ̄̐̃̇ͣ̅͂ͦ̀͊̍̎ͫ͛̽ͫ̎̌ͬ͒̈̔̌͊̉̾͂̇̋̑ͨͦ̓ͦ̾̉ͦ͂͊ͫͭ̈́ͭ̓͐ͭ̓̋͒̿̑̽̌ͥ̊̏̔̾̍ͣ̀̒̂́̂̐͒̔͒̽ͦ̇̎͒ͣ͂ͭͬ̀̎̂ͥ̃̓̂͆ͬ̈́̌̔̒̄̋̈ͯ̐̿̐̋̎̒ͭ͑ͪ̑̀ͯͬͭ̓̓͑ͫ̃͊̏͛̄̽͂̌͌ͬ̂̑ͯ̏̌̍͆̇̋̊͐̂ͣͩͯ̉͊͐ͩ̑̓̂͑ͯ̅́̊̃̉̂͆͆̈ͤ̽̎̓̌ͩ̑̈͒̽̓̐̇ͯ̈́͂̎ͣͧ͒ͩ̂ͦ̑ͦ́ͥ̅͑ͭͣͪ̓̅́͐̊̌̋̊ͥ̎ͨ̈́̊͆̆̂̽ͨ̽̍̉ͬͤ͂̈ͥ̉̈̋͑ͯ͋̌ͩͩ̏̇͌͒̋̀̄̓̇͊͐̍ͪ̔ͪ̋̋̐̌̄ͦͭ̅ͭͦͭ̆̽̽̀̂ͧ͋̓͑ͩ̈́ͧ̎̐̽̔ͩͫͯͨͮͥ͒̑͆ͨ̌͋̆̐ͦ̿ͣͧ̊̓̒͗̈̉͐ͣ̇́ͥ̌̄̆̒̒͒͊ͮ̿ͨ̉͊͗ͦ̌ͣ͌̊ͭ̒̉͒͗̈́ͯͦ͛͐ͮ͑͋̓̃̓̈̒̈ͩ͂̔̊ͣ̃̈́ͨ̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚N̿̉ͤͪ̒ͣ͒̈́̉̈́̓͊̄ͤͮ̋̉͋ͣ̑̃͗ͭͥͭ̍ͨ̐̇̒̏͛̔̅ͮͦ͌͗̆ͯͩ͊͛ͭ̈́̽̎͂̍̊̉͐̀̈͐͊̑͊ͯ̈́͒̎ͫ̄ͯ͑ͯͥ͋ͨͫ̇̓̋́̓̔͐͌ͦͨ̓ͩͧͩ̎ͪ̌͋͆̒̑ͤ̃ͥ̿̂̅̌ͩ͗̄ͧ̍̃̉ͮ͛̔͑̈ͯ̅ͬ̓͆̀́͒ͥ̈́́ͦͫ̐͋̈ͮ̓͐̿̎ͥ͋͒͌ͩͮͧ͆ͧͩ̈ͭͫ̂͋͛͑̓̉̉̈̉͋̉ͨ̉ͬ͛͐ͧ̌̄̾͛̒̏ͭ̾̉͗͂̑̾ͧ̿̆̉̾́̈̉̽ͫͨͦͦ͗ͣ̍̽̏͛̓͛̄́ͪ̄̒̾̑̐̋ͦ́̄ͥ̈́ͥ͒̄ͫ̋͌ͥͫ̅ͭͪͤͤ̃͗̋ͫͨ̉̓ͭͥ͌͗́̈̃̒̃́ͪ̈́̒̆̓ͪ̿̀͋ͧ̈́̏̾ͧ͒ͮͫ͋͑͒̓ͥ̓̽̿̍ͥ͑ͤ̾̔͌ͤ̓͆̒̀ͪͭ̄̔̌ͥͬ͌̏ͮ̒ͦͪͣ̆̐̇͊͆̽ͫ̾̅̄͑̽ͤ͂̈̌̈́ͪ͌ͦͯ̊͌̾̏̐͂̐̏̒̄̓̔ͬͪͬ̄ͬ͌̾̔̽̓̉ͫ͌̋ͫ̃ͪ̈́̊ͦͮ̋̇̑ͩ̈̀̀͒̑͐ͨͯ͑ͭͬͮ̏͐̾͗̾̿ͣ̂ͩͩ̐ͭ̔̐ͨ̔̓̉ͥ̆ͩͮ̂ͮ͗ͬ͐ͮ̿̓̐͗ͧ̐̂͛̊̑͋̊ͮ͊̈ͩ͆̎͆ͮͦ͑̎̓ͣ̈͐̓̈́͒̎̔͆̓̍͛̽͒̅ͨ̈́̌͆̄ͯ͒̍̑̋ͫ̀̾̓̆̏ͫ̽̃ͫ̉̋ͨͯ͐̈́̈̔̒̌͋́ͨ̂̀͆̿̃͐̂̃̋̍̒̈̇ͮ͂͊̾͐͐ͪ͗ͫ̀̌̾͂̅ͤ̓ͧͪ͑̆̃̄ͮͫͩ̓̓͂̉͌̓ͫ̃̏ͦ̈̈͋̐͆̏͒̃̇̍̃ͬͣ̎̈́ͪ̈̈̀̐̏̿ͬ͆ͥ̀̍̊́͌ͣͭͮ̊ͫ͌͛͗͗ͧͨͯ́̈́̃͋ͯ̀ͦͫ͑̈̈ͩͥ̑̑̂̊ͮͣ́̓̄̆̃ͣͣ͊ͤ͗̿̐̈̆͛̔̎̓̍̄͗ͧ͛̃ͦ͐ͤ́̑ͩͯͬ͐̇̆ͨ̿̾̒͑͋̾ͦ͒͒̅ͤ̉̃ͣͦ̏̔ͫ̉ͩ̆̆ͥ̈̾ͦ̍͌̃̊ͤ̇̊͋ͨ͂̒̎ͧͪ̓̏̋̂ͭͮͦ̃̀̍̓ͧ̇̄ͬ̈́̊͂̒̈ͨ̋͊́̔̇̓͂ͨ̓̂̃̈́̏́̽ͫͣ̅ͧͨ͐͋̑̆̂̾ͩͪ͂͊͒ͨͭͤ͂̒ͬ̄͊ͤ̎͐̽͂̐͑͗̋͆̾̔ͦ͊̉͌̓̈̂̔̂ͪ̈͒ͧͭ͑̓͌̈́ͫ̒́̇ͧͭͯ̈́͒̇̓ͦͬ̎͋ͩ̀̾͌̐ͩͥ͌̋͆̔̈̔̈́͆͐ͥ̽̓͑͂͂͐̈́̍̃̏ͩ̂͐͒̓̽̓̀̈́̽ͪͤ̐ͫ̊̌ͭ͗ͩ͑̾̎ͪ͂̅̿̉̉̈̏͒ͥͦͭͣ̀͂ͥ̓̓ͤͩͫ̅̋ͨ̍̓̃ͩ͋́́͐̽̓͊̑͛ͪ̉̿̑ͪͬ́̌͌͋̓̃̀͐̈́ͭͩ͋ͦ̽̃ͩ̅ͮ͛̇ͧ̇̿͐͒͗͂ͧ͒ͮ̋̇̑̃ͭ̆̒ͣ̂ͫ̏͂͊̄̔ͫͤ̅̑̎̓̏̒̽̎̃̉͑̓͆̒̊̔͆͛̑̏͛ͤͫͣͯ̋ͨͨ̽̑͗ͫ̾̽͛̍̏̀̐ͥ̿̃̅ͥ͆͒̌ͯ̅̉̍͋͑́̽́ͬ́͊̾̍ͤ̏̿̅̇̒͌̋ͣͧͬ̈ͨ͌͌ͫͬ̅͛̾ͪ̓̋́̄̑ͬͧͭ̐ͣͣ̄̐̒͌̑̀̀͗ͣ̅̾͗ͦ̑͐͒͒ͤ̃͐̑ͤͫͯ̍̌ͯ̑ͧ̓ͧ͋̿͒̔͌̋͑͑̀͋ͫͨ͊̈́ͫ́̏̉̉͋ͤ̏̒͐ͣ̎͌̀̅ͮ̄̅ͫ̃͗̾̾͌ͩ̓ͩ̈͐̇ͤ̅ͤ̇́ͦ̐͐ͤͯͭ̅̾ͫ̀̽ͯ̌ͥ̓ͯ́ͦ̾̓̾ͭ̎̓̾̐͗ͮ̓ͣͦ̇ͫ̏ͦ̾̿͑͊͛̇ͨ̈́͗͊ͩ̔̀͊ͨ̂̿ͯ̀̏͐͋̀͐͛ͬ̔ͤ̈́ͣ̇͌̿̑̇ͥ͑̇̇͛̆̿͐ͩ͛͒̒̾̅̆̽̋̅͛ͨͫ͊̔͊ͮ̄̽̔̏̽̋̃ͭ̓ͣͯ͋͌ͨ̐̏ͤ̽ͫ̃̎ͫ͌̎ͥ̉̾̂̽ͥ̐̓̈͗͌̿̿ͧ̔ͮ͌̓̎͊̉ͭ̑͑͊ͮͤ̑ͬ̌̐̈̓̆̓̏̏̔̋̀̅̂̒ͯ̈́̾̈́͌̃͐̿͌̉ͪ̈́͗͑̆ͩ́̓ͧͧ̉̌̃̉͑ͧ̏ͭ̿ͯͨ͑͋̄̉̍̐͂̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚e͛͊̃̄̏͗̎͛̄̐ͦ͐ͫ̃ͥͭ̓ͯ̈͑̒ͯͪ̎͋͗ͩͧͪ̓̇ͧͬ̎̒̊̅̅ͦ̀ͤͬ̏ͯͥ̆̈̏ͨͧͥͥ̇ͫ͌̑̀́̔̍͌̍̿ͥ̈́͐̿͋̒̏̒̎̑̉͛ͪͬ̒̑̿̈́̓̎̔̓̿̂ͤ̅́ͯ̿́́̄̍ͦ̀̈ͭ̏̎ͦͩ̋̾͛͒̽ͫ̀́ͮ̍ͣͦͩ̇͌̈͛ͦ͊͂ͨ͒̅ͭ͑̈́͗̿ͥͩͧͮ͗ͣͣͫͣͧͥ̂̆̃́ͧͧ̽͛̓͐̔̅ͫ̅ͧͬ͐̿ͯ̈́ͪ́̏͊̑͊̌ͫ̾ͬ̇͆ͭ̐ͯͦ͆̆̇͐̈͒̈́̒̐ͤ̐ͣ̾̿ͨ̇̉ͣͫͬ͆͊̂̀ͬ̋ͧ̊͌ͣͣͭͥ͆̍́͊ͬ̓̐ͣ͛̏ͩͯ͑ͥͪ̉͌͂ͭ͌̈͑̓̎̔͐̊̌͛̈́̏͌͂̂̆͑͗͒̂͛ͣ͒̑̈́̾͌ͭ̐̈̅̃͌̈́ͬ͛͑̽̈́ͯ́̈́̅ͭ̈̎̈́͐͌ͧ̄̇͂͋̓̄͂͋ͦͤͩͭͪ̋͂͌͒͑̒̄ͣ̏̈́̒ͩ̐̉̾ͨͯ̄͑ͬ̓̐ͪͥ̏͑̐̌͋̔̉̅͗́̾̍́ͩ̅ͬͧ̈̆̎͐̉̅͑̈̐ͨ̂̃ͮ̎̈͌̋̉͂̀ͩͪ̒͒͗̇ͫ̿ͩͬͦͧ͛̓̆ͣͮ̉̍ͣ̈̓ͦ͋ͯͭͩ̍ͫ́̋͌̓͊̓ͩ͂̄̇ͮͨ̍̀͐͒̒̾̍ͧ̉̆ͯ͗ͮ̀͌̂̑ͤͮ͊̾̓ͨ͒̅̈́͂ͤ̉̍͗͒ͪ̄̍ͯ́͑̌ͮ͌͒͗̏͑͊ͪ̊͗̾ͪ̓̌̒́͂̅̅̽̄̊̋̃̀̋ͥͦͣ͋̈́ͧ̊̿̄́ͣ̈́̾ͯ̈́ͬͪ̈ͥ͒̏̂ͯͥ͑̿̄̏̿ͭͥ́ͥͧͩ́̑̍͗ͧ̑ͭ̔͋̉͒͌̎ͥ͒̓ͪͦ̂ͫ́̈́ͪ̍ͨͣ̃̌͂̇̍̄ͨ̀͛̓̇̀͋̉̎ͮͣ͋ͧͣͯ̿̆ͣ̃̊ͣ͗̾ͤ͂̽ͫ́͛̈́̌͑͐͑̎̏̑̌̃͂͛͐̔̔ͮ͊̾̎͑̏̃͋ͫͪ̇ͭ̈̈̇̈ͪ̾̎ͪ͑͆̃̈́ͫ̎͛ͣ͗̎̉͒͂ͮ̾ͥ́͋̀͊̄͌ͣ̀̆̆͑̍͊͂̐̽͂̓ͧ̈́̉̽͑̑̾̏̾ͭ̈̎̎̔͛̏̔́̏ͧ͐̎͌͊ͣ̎͊͒͑͋ͦͧ̂ͪ̊͌̿̿̄̓̉̎̏̿̑ͨ͂̃̐ͤ̍̾ͯ̍̎̾͋̿ͤͥͤͥ̃̆͊̔ͩ͂̄ͭ̋̇̍̓̆̿̀̊̋ͤ̋̐̃͑̉̌̈́̅̽̾͊̓̓ͪ̃̒ͯ̅̆̽ͭͪ̐͒ͯ̂͐͗̈́ͦͣ͑́ͦ͊ͣͨ̒̽̈́̽̂̿͂̇̍ͣ̏̓̾̋̂̔́ͥ̊̓ͭ̊ͨ̈́̃̏͑̀͋ͣ̅͌ͥ̐̍͗͋̈́̔̌ͦ́ͫ͛͂͂̓̒͌ͬ͊̋̔ͥ̿́ͤ̅̽̂ͨ͗͋̀͛̊̐͐̓̎͑̉͐̅̇͌̏̒ͭ͛ͤ̑͌͊̔̃ͩ͒ͥͬ̽̄̀ͫ̃̀̾̄ͦ͛͌ͩͥͭ͂̽ͥ̿͆̍̉ͤ̍̌̓ͤ̊͂͗̂ͩͬͤ͆͊̆̇̉̽ͣ̊ͬ̋̊̑̀͗̆ͣ͌̀ͪ͆ͭ̐̄͊ͧ̋͂̾̽͌̃ͦ̔́̅ͨ͛ͩ̿̓͛ͭ͌͑ͬ̔̾͊̑͊ͫ̊̍ͫ̊̐̋̾͋͂ͮ͐̎̃͂̒̅̐̉ͧͯͭͪ̽͑̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚

Comment: What browser are you using? I don't see what's shown in the image at http://wot-news.com.

Comment: Tested in mozila, chrome, yandex browser. I can paste them there and you will see

Comment: Maybe time to change the ribbon?

Comment: I've looked at the site in Chrome, Firefox, and IE11. Nothing.

Comment: its allready deleted on forum

Comment: Okey, just look there

Comment: Looks like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3372061 :)

Answer (score 0):

These are the [Hangul Syllables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul_Syllables) unicode block that will render the Modern Korean language. If it just looks like a vertical smear you need to install the [Korean Language Package](http://www.koreanfluent.com/cross_cultural/korean_keyboard/korean_keyboard.htm).